# Gitlab Runner Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm facing this issue while building the docker file I have installed gitlab-runner version 13.8.0
`gitlab runner cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue disabling the TLS by adding a variable in .gitlab-ci.yml `variables: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''` and updating volumes in runners config.toml file located in system where gitlab-runner is installed `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock" "/cache"]`